Best framework for a custom ERP
I am currently working as a developer at a company that manufactures and sells machines and equipment intended for the industrial sector.
This company is currently using an ERP tool with a QML frontend and a Python backend. This tool was not originally designed by a professional developer, and while it is still usable today, more and more features are becoming unsustainable in the long term. New developments are based on poor programming principles, which perpetuates the software's lack of maintainability.
I am therefore considering the following question: what would be the best framework to develop from scratch an internal ERP for a company that would allow for several things:

Complete tracking of the company's projects, from order confirmation to after-sales service, including the sharing of production plans between a design office and a workshop, and the production stages of orders
An open-source framework that would allow a small team to work effectively on the same project and ensure the software's maintainability (the company is currently small, but the software should remain viable even if the company experiences significant growth)
A cross-platform application (Windows, Mac, Android, iOS) that would ensure the software's security against cyber attacks
Integration with external APIs (e.g., Outlook REST API)

After doing some research, I've seen people using Django, a framework I'm already quite familiar with, but I'm not sure if it's the most suitable for my situation.
PS: I know this is a huge project, but I’m curious to know what possibilities I might have with this challenge.
Thank you for your feedback!

I suggest looking at ERPNext

It is opensource.
It is based on Frappe framework, hence extensible.
It is currently one of the popular opensource implementations.

